# Git: determine revision based on file contents

Tags: git, revision

I have a file from a project that uses GIT as repository. For that file I need to find out to which revision this file belongs to. The file is stand-alone outside of an repository (not tracked) therefore the standard git commands do not work.

Is there a way to determine the revision this file belongs to only based on its filename and its content?

Comment: i don't understand your question. Is your file tracked or not tracked?

Comment: Outside of an repository means "not tracked".

Comment: @Robert "Outside of the repository", to me, means that it was never tracked which would mean there is no version of it, therefor invalidating your question.  I think the wording you're looking for is that the file has been tracked at some point in time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there's a one-shot command to do this - git's object model makes it quite laborious to work back from a blob to commits that might reference it.  Here's one way of doing it, though.  First of all, find the hash of the file that git would use, with:

```
git hash-object foo.c
```

Suppose that returns `f414f31`.  Then you can use a script like the following:

```
for c in $(git rev-list --all)
do
   ( git ls-tree -r $c | grep f414f31 ) && echo Found the blob in commit: $c
done
```

... to show all the commits that contain that blob.  If you want to know which branches those commits are on,  you can do:

```
git branch -a --contains 1a2b3c4d
```

Comment: A more robust check for the presence of the right hash would be `git ls-tree -r $c | cut -f 1 | cut -d' ' -f 3 | grep f414f31`: in principle, one of the file names could contain a hash number (though this is not be typical), and the two cut commands precisely select the git hashes (and leave out the file names).