# Get version of a source file

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GIT: determine revision based on a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387768/git-determine-revision-based-on-a-file)

I have a source file (e.g. foo.py) which is under version control in git. The file I have is an old version. But I don't know which version. How can I get the version of this file?

Since git uses hash values, it should be possible to calculate the hash value and get the matching reversion.

Is there a way to get the closest match if the file was changed outside the git repository?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7387768/223092