# SVN: Way to determine revision by comparing file or file content

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, cornerstone

I have a scenario where I have a file and I need to know what revision in source this file is.

I may have hundreds of revisions on a particular file and have a file that matches one or more of those revisions.
Is there any way in Tortoise, Cornerstone or through the command line to do this?

Apologies if the question isn't the clearest. To be honest I'm not sure how to phrase what I'm looking for.

I found a similar question about git here;

[GIT: determine revision based on a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387768/git-determine-revision-based-on-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cribbing a bit off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721533/1698557), here's a quick and dirty batch file that will do the job, assuming the input file is already under version control.

```
@echo off

set file=%1
set temp_file="temp.file"

if [%file%] == [] (
  echo Usage: "%0 <file>"
  exit /b
)

for /F "tokens=1 delims=-r " %%R in ('"svn log -q %file%"') do (
  svn cat -r %%R %file% > %temp_file%
  fc %temp_file% %file% > nul
  if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo Matches revision r%%R
  del /Q %temp_file%
)
```

This gets the log for the filename given, and for each revision does the following:

- dumps the version of the file at that revision to a temporary file on disk
- compares the dumped revision with the input file
- if they're equivalent, `fc` sets `errorlevel` to 0, so check for that and output `Matches revision r###`
- removes the temporary file

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use *any content* outside VCS and identify corresponding resisions and don't add this data to file (text file) or repository (binaries) - it's **your fail** (Git-boys **must** suffer and be excruciated, because they haven't keywords directly /but have smudge|clean filters/ and revision properties /?/, but in SVN you have these possibilities). Re-think about your workflow and start using Power!

In your current state (no keywords, no metadata) you can (for each file)

- calculate *any available* hash for unversioned file
- calculate the same hash for this file for all revisions in question in repo
- compare hashes and find a match(es)