# Guess a file's revision number by trawling the repository

Tags: svn

I've got a file that is sitting outside of version control (and contains no handy `$id$` or `$revision$` keywords).  I know that this file corresponds to one that's under version control.  However, I don't know what *revision* of the version-controlled file is the same as my file.

Is there a way of searching back through the history for the version-controlled file until I find one that's the same as the one sitting outside of version control?

(I'm sure I could write a script to do this, but I'm hoping that there's already a cunning tool or `svn` command that does something very similar.)

Comment: No, you have to reinvent the wheel (and start using keywords)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why my question has been voted down.  A vote down means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and since there's apparently no obvious solution, it can't be the "research effort" reason.  I assume it's not unclear since nobody has asked for clarification, and it's useful to me or I wouldn't have asked it.

Comment: @LazyBadger I thought there mightn't be an easy solution.  Unfortunately, keywords are not always the answer to this kind of issue.  What if my file's a binary file like an image?  Keywords wouldn't help then.

Comment: Obvious solution exist, such questions was asked even here some times... thus, really "not useful"

Comment: Fair enough.  You must be better at searching than me because I didn't manage to find anything!  Could you direct me to some of those solutions please?  (I've just searched again and still come up blank.  I can find lots of things about searching in subversion but nothing that helps with what I'm asking.)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222814/svn-way-to-determine-revision-by-comparing-file-or-file-content) with my useless rant and useful bat-file from [Patrick's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39225642/960558)

Comment: Thank you, that'll do nicely.